# Converting coordinates of SKNodes that have different parent nodes?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I have a game scene with a player and enemy.  Each player has a head and two hands nodes.  I am trying to move a player's hand to the opponent's head node.

Here is what the node tree looks like:

```
Scene
    Player
        Head
        Left Hand
        Right Hand

    Opponent
        Head
        Left Hand
        Right Hand
```

How would you move the player's left hand to the opponent's head with `convertPoint:FromNode:` since they have different parent coordinate systems?

Comment: They both have a common parent in Scene, right ? Once you have calculated the point in the scene for each, you then can calculate the offset to move the hand in it's own coordinate space.

Comment: Also, your question is a duplicate of  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21863918/sknode-convertpoint-tonode-fromnode-confusion