# Transfer global to local node position in SceneKit

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

So far, I figured out how to convert a local node position to global values in Swift (worldTransform).

My question is: How can I convert it the other way round? (due to rotation, x/y/z axis of the childnodes might be altered).

I know it has something to do with convertPosition, but I can't find any reference that helps me understanding it.

This is what I want to do:
Node A is a child of rootNode and has a position A.
Node B is a child of rootNode and has a position B and a rotation B.
Node B1 is a childnode of Node B with local coordinates within it.
I want to move Node B1 to Node A's position and replace it.

How do I translate Node A's coordinates to the local system of Node B?

Cheers

Comment: Please have a look at this excellent answer: [SKNode convertPoint toNode & fromNode confusion?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21980663/172695)

Comment: @SebastianDressler That question is about Sprite Kit, this is about Scene Kit.

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist while you are totally right, IMO it is still related.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have to express the new transform in the coordinate system of `nodeB1`'s parent, and from

1. either the coordinates system of `nodeA`'s parent

   `nodeB1.transform = [nodeB1.parentNode convertTransform:nodeA.transform fromNode:nodeA.parentNode];`
2. or the world coordinates system

   `nodeB1.transform = [nodeB1.parentNode convertTransform:nodeA.worldTransform fromNode:nil];`

of course you can replace `nodeB1.parentNode` by `nodeB`, and in this case `nodeA`'s parent is the root node